# Integrate Salesforce with HP TRIM

Tags: salesforce, integration, apex-code, force.com

I am a Salesforce Developer and want to integrate Salesforce with HP TRIM.
I am new to HP TRIM. Can someone please suggest what steps should I follow in order to integrate both systems.

1. Does HP TRIM provide API/ WSDL that I can consume in Salesforce ?
2. Do I have to use Java or C# to integrate OR I can do it using APEX(Salesforce) only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Salesforce, but I've done a lot of dev with TRIM.

There is both a .NET API and a SOAP web service. The .NET API is much easier to work with, but using it will depend on how well Salesforce interops with .NET.

I prefer to write my own web services that use the .NET API, and have everything consume that. Because TRIM is so configuration heavy it makes sense to simplify it with some nice domain specific abstractions.

Documentation is scarce, and is only available in the HP TRIM software package, but once you get up and running it's fairly straight forward.

The [HP TRIM product page](http://www8.hp.com/au/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1173707#.Uh_y8WSMG3N) has a trial you can download.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Troy. As per your suggestion, downloaded a trial version of TRIM. I'm in process of getting familiar with TRIM. 
When I open TRIM and select a dataset, it gives me an error like "Your licensing information could not be read". 
First I want to evaluate TRIM for its features but I could not find a way to get the evaluation license. 
Tried contacting HP support several times. Working on it. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

TRIM is now in the 9th version. As a former developer on the product, I can assure you that the latest version has an eval license built in so you can download and try it for a period of time.

It comes with a built in .Net SDK, via the TRIMSDK.dll and a COM SDK, which I think is in the process of being deprecated.

In addition, the crew has built up an API, which is a restful web service API returning data in JSON. Very handy for anyone wanting to build web based TRIM integrations.

Oh, and its no longer called TRIM. Version 7 = TRIM, Version 8 = HP Records Manager (or HPE Records Manager) and Version 9 = HPE Content Manager.